# NextJS process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC variable is empty in production

Tags: kubernetes, next.js, dockerfile, gitlab-ci

I have a NextJS "^11.1.2" app, which gets build in a Dockerfile and deployed to production via CI/CD. **But my `process.env` variables are not rendered**

I have this in my client side code, which should be rendered at runtime:

`const PublicApiUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL;`

In my (Gitlab) **CI/CD Pipeline** I added via AUTO_DEVOPS_BUILD_IMAGE_EXTRA_ARGS some `--build-args`, as well `ENV` and `ARG`:

```sh
AUTO_DEVOPS_BUILD_IMAGE_EXTRA_ARGS --build-arg=NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=https://my.api.com --build-arg=NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=https://my.api.com --build-arg=NEXT_PUBLIC_BUILDER_KEY=XXXXXX
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=https://my.api.com
API_URL=https://my.api.com
```

**Dockerfile**

```
ARG API_URL
ENV API_URL=$API_URL
ARG NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=$NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL
ARG NEXT_PUBLIC_BUILDER_KEY
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_BUILDER_KEY=$NEXT_PUBLIC_BUILDER_KEY
RUN npm run build # which resolves in "build": "next build"
```

This values below are definitely picked up (I did a `RUN env` and can see the variables are there).

This is my `configMap` at Kubernetes which mounts the `.env.local` file into the container:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: frontend-env-local
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/resource-policy": keep
data:
  .env: |-
    NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=https://my.api.url
    API_URL=https://my.api.url
```

This is my deployment which mounts the `configMap` into the container as `.env.local`:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend
  labels:
    app: frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          items:
          - key: .env
            path: .env.local
          name: frontend-env-local
        name: frontend-env-local
      imagePullSecrets: 
        - name: gitlab-credentials
      containers:
        - name: frontend
          image: "registry.gitlab.com/myapp:latest"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 5000
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /app/.env.local
            name: frontend-env-local
            readOnly: true
            subPath: .env.local
```

When I locally build `next build` it works and my variable is rendered.

But when I push, build and deploy it and run the app, its an empty string:

```
const PublicApiUrl = "";
```

**Why is the variable not recognized by NextJS?**

I logged into production (Kubernetes pod) terminal and run `env`. The variables are present too.

## Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: What are you using like hosting?

Comment: @illiachill Kubernetes

Comment: I had the same issue on Docker. Please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71778031/nextjs-public-environment-variable-not-working-on-azure-app-service/74503166#74503166

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had to define the variables also in my `next.config.js` like so:

```js
module.exports = {
    serverRuntimeConfig: {
        API_URL: process.env.API_URL,
    },
    // Will be available on both server and client
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
        NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL,
    }
}
```

After that change it seems that neither the `configMap` nor the mounted volume was needed... Only the `--build-arg` in my CI/CD as well and the `ARG` and `ENV` in the `Dockerfile`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define variables in your `next.config.js` - bad practice.

Define your `env` files separately

**For your local:**

You need to create `environments` folder, then create your `.env.local` inside this folder; here you define your local variables.
Once you did this, in your fill the `package.json` file, in `scripts` section:

```
"scripts": {
    //you need to add this line - defining your .env.local file inside 
    "local": "env-cmd -f environments/.env.local node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
  },
```

so, after you start your `local server` with npm command as `npm run local`

**For your server:**

you need to define somehow `environment variables` on your server. On vercel it's in `settings/environment variables`

P.S. you are "missing" the value of your `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL` because `.env` files are normally ignored by GitHub - you newer expose your environment variables. Your file `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL` is missing on the server, it's why u have `null` value.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `Docker`, check if `.env` file is in the DockerFile before you'll make the build of the project.

```
Example DockerFile:
FROM node:16.14.0-alpine3.14 as build

WORKDIR /app

# Copy in only the parts needed to install dependencies
# (This avoids rebuilds if the package.json hasn’t changed)
COPY package.json  .
COPY package-lock.json .
COPY .env.production .

# Install dependencies (including dev dependencies)
RUN npm install

# Copy in the rest of the project
# (include node_modules in a .dockerignore file)
COPY . .

# Build the project
RUN npm run build

# Second stage: runtime
FROM node:16.14.0-alpine3.14

WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV=production

# Again get dependencies, but this time only install
# runtime dependencies
COPY package.json  .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm install --only=production

# Get the built application from the first stage
COPY --from=build /app/.next/ /app/.next/

# Set runtime metadata
ENV PORT 3000
EXPOSE 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
env.production
```

Verify that you have the file above in the root of your Nextjs project, if not create one.

Then, add your secret key(s) for example

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_SITE_URL=https://dankore.com
```

CAUTION: You do not need to add the value of the secret as I did above, however, you need to add it to your server somehow.

Reference: [Nextjs default Environment Variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#default-environment-variables)