# NextJS public environment variable not working on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, next.js, environment-variables, azure-web-app-service

I have a **NEXT_PUBLIC** environment variable in my NextJS application. It has been set in my *.env.local* file and working correctly but after it has been deployed to Azure App Service the app is unable to read it. It is *'undefined'*. I have configured it under Configuration for the App Service.[image]

Any advice on what the issue might be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution? because I have the same problem atm.

Comment: @Max I was unable to resolve the PUBLIC issue but to resolve the issue I was facing was to make use of getServerSideProps. Then I don't need the PUBLIC environment variable. Hope you find a solution. If you do please add it for everyone else to see.

Comment: @Max did you find a solution by any chance? Having a similar issue.

Comment: @Gericke sorry I didn't find a solution.

Comment: Any updates on the solution? Facing similar issue.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem that the **NEXT_PUBLIC** environment variables on my Azure AppService always had the value "undefined", although they were defined as environment variables in the AppService settings.

When building the Docker image, the NEXT_PUBLIC environment variables are set directly during the build and cannot be overwritten afterwards. This was the reason why the settings from the AppService for the NEXT_PUBLIC did not work.

The following solution by Renato Pozzi ([dev.to](https://dev.to/itsrennyman/manage-nextpublic-environment-variables-at-runtime-with-docker-53dl)) helped me.

Here are my steps: (next v.12.2.5):

a) Create the desired NEXT_PUBLIC variable in the Dockerfile before the "build" process start and fill it with a "placeholder value".

```
RUN NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=PLACEHOLDER_NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL yarn build
```

b) Create an entrypoint file (entrypoint.sh) which replaces the placeholder value with real environment variables from the AppService when the Docker image start.

In my example, the placeholder "PLACEHOLDER_NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL" is replaced with the real value "NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL" from the AppService configurations (environment variables).

```
#!/bin/sh
test -n "$NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL"
find /app/.next \( -type d -name .git -prune \) -o -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "s#PLACEHOLDER_NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL#$NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL#g"
exec "$@"
```

c) Make the previously created entry point file known in the Dockerfile.

```
COPY --chown=nextjs:nodejs entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```